# Is there any "green" library in python for reading image and getting RGB values?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, rgb

Is there any "green" library in python for reading image and getting RGB values?

I want to get the pixels of jpeg images but I don't have the rights to install PIL module on every machine so I want to know if there is any alternative to do this?

Comment: "Green" library? What's that?

Comment: what do you mean with "get the pixels".do you want a bitmap out of a jpeg?

Comment: which environment windows, linu, osx, ...?

Comment: I just want to read the RGB values of a jpeg out for some calculation

Comment: linux , I can not install anything on OS so I can not use PIL....

Comment: do you mean "green" to standard library?

Comment: I mean portable.. no need to install it..

Comment: @Tichodroma: it's a library that offsets CO2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

may have a look at "imagemagick".

and the use stream ([manual](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/stream.php)):

```
stream -map rgb -storage-type char image.jpg pixels.dat
```

Comment: I guess if he's able to install `imagemagick` then `PIL` too.

Comment: but the chance the imagemagick is already installed is much higher.because its a very common library.

Comment: I agree with mo. Try it out. Otherwise, you don't have much options.

Comment: you can try to compile imagemagick locally against the target environment and then deploy it but this can be a mess.